# How can one prove$\int_V\text{d}V\ \vec A=0$, given that $\vec A\cdot \vec{\textbf{n}}=0$ and $\nabla\cdot\vec A=0$ without using tensor analysis?

Tags: analysis, vector-analysis, tensor-products, mathematical-physics

In the course of learning Electrodynaimics, I was asked to solve the problem following:

- *$\vec A$ is a vector normal to the boundary of a volume $V$,which means that $\vec A\cdot \vec{\textbf{n}}=0$, where $\vec{\textbf{n}}$
  is the noramal vector of the surface of the volume $V$. Besides,
  $\nabla\cdot\vec A=0$ within the volume $V$. Please prove that
  $\int_V\text{d}V\ \vec A=0$*

A standard solution is

- *$\int_V\nabla\cdot(\vec A\vec r )=\oint_S\text{d}\vec\sigma\cdot(\vec A\vec r
     )=\oint_S\text{d}\sigma\vec{\textbf{n}}\cdot(\vec A\vec
     r)=\oint_S\text{d}\sigma\ 0\times\vec r)=0$*

However, does this solution mean that a man that haven`t learned tensor analysis can never solve the problem? I wonder whether there are any other solutions without tesors.

Thank you for your reading the question. Waiting for your excellent answer.

Comment: Stoke's theorem is a mainstay of vector analysis. Tensor operations are not required for it. As with the FTC and Cauchy's theorem, it can be proved by sub-dividing the volume into many subvolumes that are so small, the integrand is effectively constant on them, and showing that this makes theorem true on the tiny subvolume. But the overall integrals of both volume and surface are the simply the sum of the corresponding integrals of the subvolumes. Thus it holds overall as well. Tensors (beyond vectors) are not needed to do this.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thanks a lot, I will try it. You are such a nice man~